# seo page issue with links inside the acticle.php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

friends so i created seo friendly blog works ok but i face a issue which is say i in menu put links like index.php | contact.php all these works find but in my article.php it don't work if i do not add full url like say http://localhost/blog/index.php

hope you get what im trying to say?

here is my article.php page how i fetch records

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    
$url = str_replace('/blog/', '', ucwords($url));


//$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,title,keyword,description,image,youtube,article,created,views  FROM article WHERE url='".$url1."'");    

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,title,keyword,description,image,youtube,article,created,views  FROM article WHERE url = :url");

$stmt->bindParam(':url', $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();    
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();

//$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if($count <1){    
        header("Location: ".$site_path."index.php");    
        exit();    
}

$qry = "UPDATE article SET views = views +1 WHERE url = :url";    
$stm = $db->prepare($qry);    
$stm->bindParam(':url', $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stm->execute();    

//mysql_query("UPDATE article SET views = views +1 WHERE url ='".$url."'");    
 //$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

and htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ article.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

how can i fix the issue in article.php page that like every other pages on my website even on this page i can add urls as index.php and any bla.php other than having to use http://localhost/blog/index.php

thanks alot

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ article.php?$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: did not work mate, my url is like

blog/article/87/lorem-ipsum-is-simply-dummy-text-of-the-printing-and-typeset the part article/87/lorem-ipsum-is-simply-dummy-text-of-the-printing-and-typeset is stored in db 

this is how the url is displaying when i click on the menu links which is a include file works fine on other pages except on this page it display strangely 
 http://localhost/blog/article/87/index.php

Comment: maybe try `$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,title,keyword,description,image,youtube,article,created,views  FROM article WHERE url = '$url'");` AND `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ article.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: or place the `$stmt->bindParam(':url', $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);` before the  `$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id...`

Comment: did this $stmt->bindParam(':url', $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id,title,keyword,description,image,youtube,article,created,views  FROM article WHERE url = '".$url."'"); but now i get blank page

Comment: i tried removing the binding but still article/87/ part from the url is conflicting with urls

Comment: What is the url of the blank page returning? Make sure that `$url` is returning the correct value with `echo $url;` what is the result? is the record in the DB matching that exact echo?

Comment: this is the url article/62/a-big-announcement-a-new-idea-or-a-special-occasio  i tried removing $stm->bindParam(':url', $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);    and replaced the htaccess code the one u gave, data displays but with urls still extra bit of article/62/ gets added by itself if i do not use absolute url. this is even conflicting with my included style and js files in this article.php page im having to add absolute to every links in this page so that it don't mess up :(

Comment: fixed mate i had to add the url in query that was causing issue :) id,title,keyword,description,image,youtube,article,url,created,views thanks alot appreciate ur help and time

Comment: I was suspecting the url was causing the issue :)

Comment: lol sorry no its not fixed still same issue, i thought i had removed the http://localhost/blog/ from one home link but no it was http://localhost/blog/index.php and i thought it was fixed. m really getting confused how on earth its fetching the article/85/ in all urls

Comment: Where are you getting '$site_path' from?